# For two or more jsp requests how many html responses

Tags: html, jsp

I have this question,
when some one clicks on submit button on a page assume this happens,
two `JSP` requests go to the server.

1. Would there be two htmls or just one html response by the server.
2. If there is only one html response for Two `JSP` requests, how is this achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Http works this way: when you send a request, you get back a response. It's as simple as that. So if you send 2 requests, you'll get back 2 responses.

Comment: Why would clicking on a submit button trigger two HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

> Would there be two htmls or just one html response by the server
>   `response` object will be created for each http request. so if you provide two requests , there will be two response objects in turn.

If you are considering in terms of view , there will be only one view returned . it can either through `RequestDispatcher` or `sendRedirect`.

See [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading)